# Handling Cyclic Dependencies in GUI Components

Tags: oop, design-patterns, user-interface, event-handling

I have a design problem for which I'm sure a design pattern exists, and I want to know that pattern and get more insight into the best practice for attacking it.

I have an interactive interface for entering a time interval. This time interval has restrictions on the number of days (d), hours (h), minutes (m) and seconds(s):

d <= c (c is given)

h:m:s <= 5:30:00

[image]

In the above interface, you can manually change the knobs (those circular gauges) to obtain a value for every parameter (there are 4 knobs, 3 concentric and 1 independent). Besides, you can edit the textboxes yourself and the knobs are supposed to reflect your changes. Of course, as you rotate the knobs, you're getting changes in values *during rotation*, not after your movement stabilizes. This means a hell of events firing and numerous corner cases to handle. For example, imagine h:m:s to be 4:38:00 and the user increments the hours. Instead of the simple 5:38:00, it should be 0:08:00 besides incrementing the days, or 5:30:00 if the day is already a maximum.

What happens currently is that all the logic is written in the `TextChanged` event of the textboxes, and the knobs' `ValueChanged` events just change the text in the appropriate textbox thus firing its `TextChanged` event. So the general question is, how can one handle such a scenario - where many objects change each other and depend on each other in a circular way?? Notice that as you're rotating the knob, a change can be refused by the textbox thus reassigning a previous value to the knob's pointer "while rotating".

Answer (score 0):

I think [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) could apply well to your scenario. You have:

- one model that contains days, hours, minutes and seconds, plus the business logic for handling changes to any of them and reflecting it on the others as required (in .NET you could use [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx))
- two views: textboxes and knowbs
- two viewmodels, one for each view, that can handle events from the view and pass them to the model, as well as handling changes on the model and reflecting them to the view

This approach isolates the two views and lets you maintain the logic around the values in one single place (the model or a Controller if you want to add an [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)).
The viewmodels also encapsulate the way you want to handle events on the UI.